# How do you get core data models into a framework?

Tags: file, core-data, static, package

I have created a framework for my core data project, that parses and stores a specific feed into core data. I want to package this framework so that whenever I want to parse this feed again I can just drag the framework into another project. However, when I try to drag my framework into another project the new project is unable to find the Core Data model (even though I have included it in the framework).

I found that if I include the Core Data Model in the framework and then drag the Core Data Model files (there is one called DataModel.xcdatamodeld and another called DataModel.xcdatamodel) into my new project, the project can then find the core data model and parse and store data as expected...there are some pictures attached to illustrate the two data models I have to include in my framework and the two models I have to drag into a new project.

Can anyone explain why this works? It doesn't seem right thatI need to have two copies of the data models, one in the framework and the other in the project for the framework to work...Is there anyway I can package up the whole of my core data and parsing project with the data models so i can just drag it into another project? That would include all these files listed below:

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

May I ask you to post a snippet of code that you use to instantiate the core data stack for the model?
If the code uses the main bundle to get the model resource (many simple core data examples do that), it will not work since the model resource is located within the framework (which is not a main bundle in your case). You will have to use something like this to init your model:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectModel*)createModelForClass:(Class)modelClass
{
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = 
    [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles: 
     [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSBundle bundleForClass: modelClass]]];
    NSAssert(model != nil, @"Unable to initialize a data model");    
    return model;
}
```

where you pass a class of any type defined within your framework. I normally create a class that serves as a facade/umbrella to the model defined within the framework and use it when calling the method above.